# How to update the particular objects in given array using mongodb query

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have the following structure in mongodb document

Note : ***Mongodb Version 3.4***

```
{
    "_id" : "1",
    "settings" : {
   "shapes":[  
      {  
         "shape":"square",
         "color":"blue"
      },
      {  
         "shape":"circle",
         "color":"red"
      },
      {  
         "shape":"round",
         "color":"black"
      }
   ]
   }
}
```

Here i want to update the shape `square & round`, because `value` array i am having this two shapes.below code i tried but it is not working my expected.

> my code

```
var value= [
      { 
        "shape":"square",
        "color":"yellow"
      },
      {
        "shape":"round",
        "color":"blue"
      }
    ]

db.Colleges.update({"_id" : "1"},{
    $set : {
        "settings.shapes": value
    }
},{multi:true})
```

> After update i need this output

```
{
    "_id" : "1",
   "shapes":[  
      {  
         "shape":"square",
         "color":"yellow"
      },
      {  
         "shape":"circle",
         "color":"red"
      },
      {  
         "shape":"round",
         "color":"blue"
      }
   ]
}
```

> I am getting output

```
{
    "_id" : "1",
   "shapes":[  
      {  
         "shape":"square",
         "color":"yellow"
      },
      {  
         "shape":"round",
         "color":"blue"
      }
   ]
}
```

actually here shape circle and color red is getting disappear, kindly any one update my code.

var `value` array not a static array, it is dynamic based on objects we to update the document.